# Error: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Lambda, SAM and DynamoDB. I want to select a record from DynamoDB Table by matching the `email` attribute which is defined as the sort key in table definition in the `template.yml`. When I invoke the function, all I get is this:

```
{"errorType":"ValidationException","errorMessage":"The provided key element does not match the schema"}
```

Here's the SAM template definition

```
  CustomersTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 50
        WriteCapacityUnits: 100
      AttributeDefinitions:       
        -
          AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "email"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "email"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
```

And here's the NodeJS code.

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid'); 
const dynamodb = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb');
const docClient = new dynamodb.DocumentClient(); 
const tableCustomers = process.env.TABLE_CUSTOMERS;
 
exports.handlerFunction = async (event) => {
 
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body); 
    const email = (body.hasOwnProperty('email'))  ? body.email : null;   

    let emailData = await docClient.get({
        TableName: tableCustomers,
        Key: { email: email },
        AttributesToGet: ['email']
    }).promise(); 
 
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ EMAILDATA: emailData }),
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Allow from anywhere 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST" // Allow only GET request 
        },
    };

    // All log statements are written to CloudWatch
    console.info(`response from: ${event.path} statusCode: ${response.statusCode} body: ${response.body}`);
    return response;
}
```

What could be wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Your query is missing a value for the partition key `id`.

Your table schema has a [composite primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey) of `id` ("Hash" or "Partition" Key) and `email` ("Range" or "Sort" Key).  `docClient.get` executes a [DynamoDB query operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html), which finds items based on primary key values:

> You must provide the name of the partition key attribute and a single value for that attribute. Query returns all items with that partition key value. Optionally, you can provide a sort key attribute and use a comparison operator to refine the search results.